# How can I track a user with Google Analytics and Parse.IO?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to find out how I can track users in Google Analytics and Parse through some sort of ID that I can use both on GA and Parse. For example: In my Parse browser I can go to the Users table and see users that register every day on my app. Each user is assigned an ObjectID in Parse. I would like to use this objectID and match the user with its Behavior analytic in GA. Is ObjectID the way to do this? Can I use GA's Client Id to find a user in Parse? Is there a better method for this?

My purpose for doing this is that I want to be able to look up a user in my Parse browser, look at his/her ClientID so I can then track that user's behavior with GA'S behavior analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use objectId because it's unique identifier and this is exactly what you need. If you want you can also create your own unique id and store in an additional field of the user but I don't see any reason to do it. ObjectId can give you what you need and also it's good because you can do quick query from parse DB since it is a unique index

To store your GA Client ID in parse please use the following code:

**Android version**

```
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.put("GAClientId","{YOUR_GA_CLIENT_ID}");
    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

        }
    });
```

**IOS Swift version**

```
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user?.setObject("{YOUR_GA_CLIENT_ID}", forKey: "GAClientId")
    user?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    })
```

**JavaScript Version**

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
user.set("GAClientID","{YOUR_GA_CLIENT_ID}");
user.save().then(function(){
    // success callback
},function(err){
    // error callback
});
```

Comment: But how can I use ObjectID to know an specific user in the Behavior analytics in GA? GA provides a Client ID per user but I do not know how I can match it with an ObjectID in Parse. @RanHassid

Comment: Can you Store additional fields inside it? Another alternative to store GA client id inside the user parse object ..

Comment: If I can store additional values to the ObjectID, how can I save the GA Client ID in Parse? @RanHassid

Comment: How can Parse get that GA Client ID and save it? @RanHassid

Comment: Hi, it's pretty simple.. but i first need to know where exactly you get the GA client id?

Comment: I edit the question with how to save GA Client id into your parse user

Comment: This has been helpful but that's where I'm having difficulties, I can't find where to get the or how to get the GA Client ID. For example, in your Javascript code, where can I get `user.set("GAClientID","{YOUR_GA_CLIENT_ID}");` @RanHassid

Comment: So it's not a question related to parse but its more related to Google Analytics... can you please post some GA code that your are using i think maybe it's better to send the current user objectId and store it in GA instead of storing GA client id in parse

Comment: Well I want to be able to know the Behavior analytics (found in GA) of Parse   users created. So, when a user is created in Parse, if I have the GA Client ID for the specific user than I can track him/her with GA's Behavior analytics. I believe saving the GA Client ID in Parse would be a very practice to keep track of users. I could be wrong though. @RanHassid

Comment: Does GA provide some kind of identifier for you? i am asking because usually GA should get values from the app and not provide ones..

Comment: Hey, you mind if we move this to the chat? @RanHassid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120605/discussion-between-ran-hassid-and-feners).